# Display the selected text into textblock

Tags: c#, xaml

I want to dispaly selected text into a textbox and i did this thing.

Look at this code:

```
    <StackPanel>
    <TextBox Name="select" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" SelectionChanged="TextBox_SelectionChanged" MinLines="7">"Asta e valoarea noastră în acest moment. 
        Vedeţi în ce condiţii mizere se antrenează copiii la nivelul juvenil.
        Ce să facă antrenorii la loturile naţionale de juniori? Fraţilor, 
        cînd vin nemţii sau austriecii îţi dau 5-6! 
        Tot timpul am dorit să se lucreze la nivelul de copii şi juniori. 
        Cînd am ajuns la Steaua, la centrele de copii erau antrenori care n-aveau nici o treabă cu fenomenul. Am venit cu oamenii mei şi am început să facem treabă", a spus Piţurcă.</TextBox>
    <TextBox Margin="10" BorderThickness="0" Name="asd"></TextBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Code c#:

```
  private void TextBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
        if(select==null)
        {
            asd.Text = select.SelectedText;
        }
  }
```

Why is my selected text not showing up?

Answer (score 2):

Since this is WPF, you should consider *not* using the code behind, and just using a binding:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=select, Path=SelectedText}"/>
```

Otherwise, invert the `null` check in your code-behind.

Answer (score 1):

You did the `null` check wrong, you want to check if the value is *not* `null`:

```
    if(select!=null) // use !=
    {
        asd.Text = select.SelectedText;
    }
```

Comment: +1 for getting it working, even if a binding would be better :)